# How do I resolve this BuildConfig error in grails

Tags: mysql, grails

There was an error loading the
`BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates mysql:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.bin, expected format is <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version> (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

This is the error I am facing when trying to run `grails app`

The part of the code containing the `mysql connector` is

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

     runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java-5.0.8'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the dash before the version number with a colon, i.e.

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

     runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.0.8'
}
```

BTW, 5.0.8 is pretty old. Unless you have a specific reason to use this version, you should use a more recent version instead, e.g. 5.1.32

Comment: @user2553958 try updating to a more recent version